# Search for strings in a char* array

Tags: c++, string, arduino, c-strings

In a project on an Arduino Uno I need to enter strings as this:

```
DDRS,parm1,parm2,...parm4 <cr>
```

The number of parmeters is variable, but at least one but can not exceed 4 and delimiter always a comma.

Command can be 3 or 4 chars only ASCII

I put the commands into an array like this:

```
char* Str[6] = {"ANA", "ANAR, "DDR", "DDRS", "DIGW", "DIGR"};
```

And read a line

```
void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available() == 0) return;
    String  Line = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');         /* \r ==  CR  */
    int     ComPos = Line.indexOf(',');
    String  Cmd    = Line.substring(0,ComPos);

    /* here for test purposes     */

    Serial.print(Line);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(Cmd);
    Serial.println();

    for (int n = 0; n < 6; ++n)
    {
      if (Str[n] == Cmd)
      {
          Serial.print("OK pÃ¥ index[");
          Serial.print(n);
          Serial.print("]");
          Serial.println();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but my problem is, it does not work. I guess it's because `Cmd` is string and `Str` is `char*`.

I have searched the web (Arduino community too) for routines to do it. I can't find any (probably me doing a wrong search), so I am stuck here.

This index-number will be used later to do (some) more differentiation.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Apparently Arduino's `String` class does not support comparing with null-terminated byte strings. The easiest solution would be to convert your array to an array of `String`, otherwise you'll have to write your own C-style string comparisons (something like `if(strcmp(Cmd.c_str(), Str[n]) == 0)`)

Comment: HI, Thanks for the code-tip.  I changed  Line 1 to: String = Str[6] = {.... }   That did  the job. Now I works. Strangely : When I first coded it i did use String Str[6] = {.....}; and it did not worked. Well, now it does , so Thanks again.  !